# Assign sequential number to integer element in array

Tags: arrays, matlab, replace, sequential

Good morning/afternoon~

I have an array like this,

```
A= [12 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 66 0 0 0 0 20 0 0 2 0 31 0 0  42 0 32 0 38]
```

the output should be:

```
B= [ 1 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 3  0 0 0 0  4 0 0 5 0  6 0 0  7  0 8  0 9]
```

What should I do to replace the non-zero elements in A with sequential number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do it:

```
A(A ~= 0) = 1:nnz(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A(ismember(A,A(A(:) ~=0))) = 1:numel(A(A(:) ~=0))
```

Answer (score 0):

With the image processing toolbox (will give the same label to adjacent non-zero values, though):

```
B = bwlabel(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
B = cumsum(A ~= 0) .* (A ~= 0);
```